# How to boot into Safe Mode in Dell Optiplex 760 - F8 key not working

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, boot, keyboard, safe-mode

I am having some major issues with an Dell Optiplex 760.

**The Issue:**

So an error comes up after I select an account to login it gives the error:

> The User Profile Service failed the logon. User profile cannot be
>   loaded.

I'm using Windows 7 Professional.

A way to fix that issue is if you can get to Safe Mode but the <kbd>F8</kbd> doesn't work.

I tried multiple keyboards nothing and another way to load Safe Mode is by `msconfig` but I cannot load into windows to make them changes. The furthest I can go is the account selection screen(I only have that one account) and then when selected shows that error.

However I can load to Boot Device Menu when pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>, but can't seem to find a way to load Safe Mode with it.

This has been bugging me for days done research and nothing really useful came out.

Answer (score 0):

You can force a Windows computer to boot in safe mode without using the F8 key by using msconfig. The following link walks you through the process for Win7, Win8, and Win10, but it's similar for older versions. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/force-windows-to-boot-into-safe-mode-without-using-the-f8-key/

Comment: Thanksfor the help but it doesnt let me go through the account stage for me to follow that process,

Comment: The only other thing I can think of, then, is to force a shut-down during booting--this does not always work, and can be dangerous, but if the computer recognizes that the computer failed to start, it MAY go to the screen that allows you to get to Safe Mode.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a repair using an installation media? like cd or bootable usb e.g http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/

If you scan boot using this then try different repairs to fix the issue

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

f8 will be the button for safe mode etc, its not a computer manufacturer specific operation but OS specific.

if f8 is not working then keyboard issue, possible usb options not enable in the bios, have you an option for ps2 keyboard?

or as someone else suggested, try to interrupt the booting process so that it displays the menu anyway.

user profile error is a registry fix (renaming reg items), find a windows 7 boot disk, or obtain one and use a usb flash drive,  can be fixed via safemode with command prompt, if it will not allow you in via safemode (doesnt sometimes)